# Issues with changing URL in WebView after screenshot has been taken

Tags: ios, objective-c

Basically as the title says, I am having some issues in my WebViewAppDelegate

https://github.com/austin4195/Nucleus-iOS/blob/master/Classes/WebViewAppDelegate.m

Lines 5-48, but I believe the issue is something with defining the item that will store the value

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of issues do you have???

Comment: Mostly with making the observer store a value to be checked in the next part. "If user takes screenshot, then change url to "whatever" else stay on page" type of thing

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code:

- You have `return` statement in line 36, so your code is never called.
- `screenshotTaken` should be declared outside of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.
- You should use `self.webViewController.theWebView` instead `webViewController.webView`.

  ```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
      navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
      navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
      navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
      WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
      webViewController.urlString = @"http://files.austinapps.org/File%20Site";
      [navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:NO];
      [webViewController release];
      [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
      self.webViewController = webViewController;
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(screenshotTaken)
                                            name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
                                            object:application];
      return YES;
  }

  - (void)screenshotTaken{
      [self.webViewController.theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com/"]]];
  }
  ```